# getting Date months/ rest of days difference

Tags: date, java-8

is there a way to get these information from two dates:

1. calculate month between dates ( month for me is a complete month)
2. calculate rest of days between dates

here is my example:

start date:

> 01/01/2014

end date:

> 21/02/2014

i need a resualt like this : `months:1 days:20`

onother example:

start date:

> 15/01/2014

end date:

> 10/03/2014

i need a resualt like this : `months:1 days:25`

Comment: for first question use `Period.between(
            LocalDate.parse("01/01/2014").withDayOfMonth(1),
            LocalDate.parse("21/02/2014").withDayOfMonth(1));`

Comment: Of course this is possible. But what have you tried so far? Where is your problem?

Comment: I need to calculate the number of days betwwen two dates, the problem is in our system a complete mounth for us is ( 30 days allways) for example if there is a month with 29 days it will be for us 30 days , and if the month is 31 days it will be also 30 days. so to get the exacte number , i will need to get the number of month ( then i multiplay by 30 ) then a make a simple addition with the rest of days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Java8 Date/Time API you may do it like so,

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 21);

Period period = startDate.until(endDate);
System.out.println("months: " + period.getMonths() + " days: " + period.getDays());
```

Comment: this is what i'm looking for